# React Native / Expo - Pass Image to Preview Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, expo

I am taking a picture with the Expo camera API --

```
//CameraScreen.js

capture = async () => {
    if(this.camera){
      this.camera.takePictureAsync()
      .then( (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.props.navigation.navigate("PreviewScan", {data: data})
      })
    }
  }
```

Once I have taken the picture I want to navigate to another screen where I can preview the picture & upload / do whatever with. I tried passing the data through params and fetching in the preview screen --

```
// PreviewScreen.js

render(){

      const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('data');

      console.log(data);

      return (

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

          <Image source={data.uri} />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backButton} onPress={ () => { this.goBack() } }>
            <Image source={require('../assets/icons/back-arrow.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

But I get a Failed Prop type for source.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was to just specify the URI option in the image tag.

so

`<Image source={data.uri} />`

became

`<Image source={{ uri: data.uri }} />`